# Purpose of using super constructor in derived class

Tags: java, inheritance

I was taught that declaring the instance variables as protected is bad and it is considered bad design due to increased coupling between the super and sub classes. Instead, use a super constructor as follows:

```
public class Shape{
    private int x, y;

    public Shape(int px, int py) {
        x = px;
        y = py;
    }
}

public class Square extends Shape {
    int size;

    public Square(int px, int py, int sz) {
        super(px, py);
        size = sz;
    }
}
```

However, I was wondering what's the point or purpose of doing such a thing instead of setting the variables as proctected as even after assigning values to x and y through the super constructor, the private values still cannot be accessed. Any explanation such as an example of this use case would be appreciated!

Comment: Usually, some part of `Shape` would use its instance variables for something.

Comment: If you want to allow a sub-class to extend functionality to those variables in the base class, then they have to be protected.  Otherwise they cannot be accessed.

Comment: @markspace They could be accessed through getter methods, if you create them. The reason for protecting fields from subclasses is the same as the reason to protect fields from outside use, i.e. to ensure their integrity by only allowing local methods to access them, so they can apply integrity checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly use the variables x and y, they must be protected, but in general you can use getter and setter methods inside Shape class to controls this variables. I personally think that the last approach is better to guarantee that only Shape class change its own attributes, is a good practice and it makes lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Private fields are not inherited and that's why Protected was invented.

A class can have its own variables and these variables cannot be modified by another class.

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

[image]

If both classes are under the same Package, you can access/modify (through the constructor or getter/setter) the variables declared as private or protected. But, if variables are private and you extends from a class on another Package, you cannot do it. If the variables are protected and you extends from a class on another Package, then, you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

We use super() constructor because, imagine a different class called Rectangle that extends Shape class i.e. `Rectangle extends Shape`, even the Rectangle has got a shape and so by using the super constructor it sets the data in Parent class (i.e. Shape class). *Note: shape and Shape are different. Shape is class, shape is english word shape*

Java is mainly about code re-usability. There can be a method (let us say area()) which is common to both Square and Rectangle in the Shape class that calculates the area for both the classes. As we have already made use of super() constructor to set the attributes (i.e.x,y), *we don't have to create variables for each subclass*, we just have to call the area() method from both the sub-classes without passing any parameters.

Coming to the private and protected thing, You are correct in thinking of using protected keyword, but only when there are no validations present on x,y. Setter method is not just to set the attribute value, they are actually meant for validation:

```
public void setX(int x) {
            if(x>0)
              this.x = x;
            else 
              this.x=0;
        }
```

If you use protected keyword, then all the sub-classes or classes in the same package can access the attributes directly which is a huge threat when you are using enterprise application. `protected` keyword does not give us a chance to validate the data.

In the above code of yours, you can go ahead and use it protected ( Given there are no validations and the data you provide is always accurate). You are correct in thinking in this way. It is not completely wrong. Different approach.**Kudos**!!